# Synapse Analytics Server less Pool >> Every day morning gives problem in reading data from External Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, serverless, azure-synapse

This is on Synapse Analytics Server less Pool >> Every day morning gives problem in reading data from External Table.

I have a external table created on Synapse Analytics Pool and every day morning - for the first time , when I do a select * from external table - it says "Access check for 'READ' operation again 'https://abc.dfs.core.windows.net/container/12/' failed with HRESULT = ;0x80070005'

then once I run the select OPENROWSET command and try to run the same query again ( select top 5  * from external table ) - it works fine.

I am wondering - what may be causing this issue. Once I move to production - what if , the same issue occurs every day ? ( I mean - I can think of creating a stored proc or something to run the OPENROWSET command everyday - but wondering, is there anything else causing this issue ?)

Note - I have seen this behavior for last 4 days and since its being reproducible almost everyday - thought of seeking any inputs on this.

Have tried explaining the same with snapshots below. Thanks !!!

[image]

Comment: I've heard of reliability issues, especially on resumption of Serverless pools. How is your serverless instance resumed? If on schedule then give it say 10 minutes to "warm up" before making queries. And of course raise a issue with Azure.

Comment: The serverless instance doesn't have an option to pause/stop/resume - its all time up and running and its a truly-pay-per-usage model . thanks !!!

Comment: I see you figured the problem. For future, paste code as text instead of pictures, easier for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out and Login back to the SSMS instance made the trick to resolve this issue. One of the Microsoft team member - helped us to get the root cause as "this is caused by the expired AAD token in SSMS" + "Please make sure that you are reconnected when using SSMS/ADS if you are leaving it more than an hour."